# Are Heroku IDs in the add-on API guaranteed to me unique?

Tags: heroku

I'm writing a Heroku add-on. When Heroku sends me the provision command, they provide a heroku_id which looks like an email address. Can I assume that this ID is unique, i.e. can I use it as a primary key in my database? Will Heroku ensure that they will not send two provision commands to my addon with the same ID, unless they deprovision it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-provider-api) state:

> Only information which is immutable between requests is provided at
>   the time of provisioning.

And you can use provided `heroku_id` to [get app info](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-app-info#get-app-info)

So it's safe to assume that `heroku_id` is indeed **app id** and can not be used by other apps.